# How do I add columns to a table and retain the formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have a basic insert column code jotted down.

```
Sub InsertCol()

Columns ("BH:BL").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

But this inserts a load of blank cells.

I now need it to populate the new columns with the formulas / sequences from existing columns to either the left or right.

I thought adding columns would work the same as my rows VBA code where it inserts and copies the formula from above but alas it does not appear so at the moment

Comment: You can use `AutoFill` - record a macro while inserting a column and filling formulas from another column to the left/right.  That will show you what you need.  Also you can drop the Select: `Columns ("BH:BL").Insert Shift:=xlToRight`

Comment: Amazing. I also mish mashed and came up with a formula in the row i was most concerned about, that didnt need a direct reference to the cell previous to work out the value. This has meant that using the auto fill, it auto updates throughout the whole row and doesnt cause issues if deleted. 

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: A much easier method is to format your data as a Table.   Then all you have to do is insert your formula(s) into the first cell in a column and the rest of the column gets populated with the same formula(s).